# mysql offset with limit and desc not working properly

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

I have a query that's not working as expected,

```
SELECT * FROM replies WHERE comment_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,11
```

As shown in picture I just want one last row to return before offset that is 2, but its returning rows after id = 2 as well.

[image]

Comment: The query returns 11 rows starting with 2.   LIMIT [offset,] row_count;

Comment: I'm sure the query works as it should. You must explain better what is your expected result.

Comment: @JonathanRomer The query should return rows before id 2, in this case there is only one row before id 2. Because we have DESC in query.

Comment: @forpas please see my comment to jonathan

Comment: Post sample data so that we can check if the query should return rows before id 2.